# Adding Authentication Token to Spring Data Neo4j Rest

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data, spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j

How do I add the authentication token created by Neo4j Server to Spring Neo4j Rest configuration

**context.xml**

```
                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

                <import resource="spring-data-context.xml" />

                <bean id="graphDatabaseService"
                    class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase">
                    <constructor-arg index="0" value="http://localhost:7474/db/data" />
                </bean>

            </beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended using Jersey Client's HttpBasicAuthFilter

Your parameters should be something like:

```
            public static final String DATABASE_ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:7474/db/data";

            public static final String DATABASE_USERNAME = "neo4j";

            public static final String DATABASE_PASSWORD = "3c0a0a6ea1sdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdf2a94d";

        private String callRest(String query) {
                final String cypherUrl = ENDPOINT + "/cypher";
                Client c = Client.create();
                c.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(USERNAME, PASSWORD));
                WebResource resource = c.resource(cypherUrl);
                String request = "{\"query\":\"" + query + "\"}";
                ClientResponse response = resource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).entity(request)
                        .post(ClientResponse.class);
                String object = response.getEntity(String.class);
                response.close();
                return object;
        }
```

Latest Jersey client can be found by adding this to your mvn pom if its not already in your dependency tree.

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
                <version>1.18.3</version>
            </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the SpringRestGraphDatabase class, there are two more parameters which can be passed into Constructor which are username and password.
Here is how you should configure it.

```
<bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase">
    <constructor-arg value="http://localhost:7474/db/data"/>
    <constructor-arg name="user" value="neo4j"/>
    <constructor-arg name="password" value="******"/>
</bean>
```